# Direction specific geofence - matching user's bearing to a range of degrees for a waypoint

Tags: android, ios, cllocationmanager, skmaps, android-geofence

We are building a driving tour app that works like this - tour audio is triggered when user enters the geofence of a tour location (waypoint) in certain direction. If user enters from another direction, geofence event will not become registered.

We can get user's bearing (Android), or course (iOS) from the device, but the output is very specific, say, 191 degrees from true north. Is there a way to assign each tour location (waypoint) a range of degrees, say, 160-200 degrees, and only if user's bearing/ course falls into this range will the geofence event become registered? If not in the range, not registered?

Comment: Geofencing is implemented on the app level-http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not something specific to the Scout SDK - you can try an app level implementation based on the bearing and the previous position: [Get the direction Android app user is headed on entering a geofence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737344/get-the-direction-android-app-user-is-headed-on-entering-a-geofence)